# Preview for select options using rails tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, actionview, collection-select

I have a select box to show list shipments details.
when user mouse over through each option, I need to show a preview of each option with more details. have any solution for this problem with rails tags

```
 <%= select_tag 'cashed_shipment', options_from_collection_for_select(@cached_shipments,:id,:cached_shipment_detail,prompt: true)  %>
```

And in model, i wrote a method return the markup for each option

```
def cached_shipment_detail
  "<div class= 'dropdown-option'>
     <div class ='dropdown-header'> #{vessel_name} | #{voyage_number} | #{loading_date}</div>
     <div class = 'dropdown-preview'> more detail preview here </div>
   </div>
```

end

but the above script print as text not as markup, How I can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:html_safe`!

```
def cached_shipment_detail
   "<div class= 'dropdown-option'>
     <div class ='dropdown-header'> #{vessel_name} | #{voyage_number} | #{loading_date}</div>
     <div class = 'dropdown-preview'> more detail preview here </div>
   </div>".html_safe
end
```

Comment: it returns the string without HTML mark up, result equal to "#{vessel_name} | #{voyage_number} | #{loading_date}"

Comment: What data type of these: `vessel_name`, `voyage_number`, `loading_date`? If these are HTML markup, you will have to use `html_safe` on each of them also. I've just tested on my machine, and It worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following

```
def cached_shipment_detail
    html = <<-HTML
    <div class = "dropdown-option">
       <div class = "dropdown-header"> #{vessel_name} | #{voyage_number} | #{loading_date}</div>
       <div class = "dropdown-preview"> more detail preview here </div>
    </div>
    HTML
    html.html_safe
end
```

Hope to help